# Как отсортировать объект по сумме результатов значений?

Tags: javascript

Представлен такой объект:

```js
let obj = {
  0: { min: '2', max: '5' },    // 3
  1: { min: '12', max: '34' },  // 22
  2: { min: '1', max: '2' },    // 1
  3: { min: '6', max: '123' },  // 117
  4: { min: '-20', max: '-4' }, // -16
};

console.log(obj);
```

Нужно получить результат после сортировки:

```
let obj = {
  4: { min: '-20', max: '-4' }, // -16
  2: { min: '1', max: '2' },    // 1
  0: { min: '2', max: '5' },    // 3
  1: { min: '12', max: '34' },  // 22
  3: { min: '6', max: '123' },  // 117
};
```

Comment: вопрос то какой? где ваш код?

Comment: Никак. Объекты не сортируются

Comment: @Дмытрык, сортируются, так как ключи в объекте это строки

Comment: Пришла идея сделать два цикла, в первом цикле добавлять новое высчитанное значение к примеру `res: '-16'`, а вторым циклом уже сделать сортировку по этому значению. Не пойму только как это в виде кода реализовать

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values

Comment: точно по сумме?

Comment: объясните, зачем вообще сортировать объект?

Comment: @Pavel Nazarian для вывода полученных данных по api, которые нужно отсортировать

Comment: а Вам ключ надо сохранять? если не надо, то можно просто выдать отстортированный массив значений. Цифровой ключ, даже как строка всё равно отсортируется

Comment: @Pavel Nazarian ключ совсем не важен, главное отсортированное значение, которое потом в цикле вывожу в html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правильно выразился Konstantin Modin, сортировать нужно массив, так как это структура больше подходит для сортировки, чем объект. Думаю, стоит обратить внимание на алгоритмы и структуры данных.
Если вам нужно потом пройти циклом, то тут тоже получается, что массив подходит лучше, чем объект. Но сделал алгоритм под ваши требования.

P.S. Добавил вариант с использованием только методов массива, для меньшего объема конструкций.

P.P.S. Во всех примерах получается, что из большего вычитается меньшее. `-4 - (-20) = 16`.

```js
let obj = {
  0: {
    min: '2',
    max: '5'
  }, // 3
  1: {
    min: '12',
    max: '34'
  }, // 22
  2: {
    min: '1',
    max: '2'
  }, // 1
  3: {
    min: '6',
    max: '123'
  }, // 117
  4: {
    min: '-20',
    max: '-4'
  }, // 16
};



function getSortedObject(obj) {
  const arr = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => value); // получаем массив из значений полей объекта
  const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => (a.max - a.min) - (b.max - b.min)); // сортируем массив значений
  const result = {}; // создаем пустой объект, в который запишем новые значения.

  for (let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    result[i.toString()] = sorted[i]; // в цикле заполняем значения объекта result
  }

  return result; // возвращаем итоговый объект
}

console.log(getSortedObject(obj));


function getSortedObject2(obj) {
  const result = {};

  const arr = Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([key, value]) => value)
    .sort((a, b) => (a.max - a.min) - (b.max - b.min))
    .forEach((element, index) => {
      result[index.toString()] = element;
    })

  return result;
}

console.log(getSortedObject2(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

Для сортировки это должен быть массив. А массив можно отсортировать например так:

```js
let arr = [
  { min: "2", max: "5" }, // 3
  { min: "12", max: "34" }, // 22
  { min: "1", max: "2" }, // 1
  { min: "6", max: "123" }, // 117
  { min: "-20", max: "-4" }, // -16
];
console.log(`arr`, arr);

const sorted = arr
  .map((item) => ({ ...item }))
  .sort((a, b) => a.max - a.min - (b.max - b.min));
console.log(`sorted`, sorted);
```

Comment: А получится оставить в виде объекта, но пересобрать его? сами ключи не важно какие, пускай также останутся 0, 1, 2 ,3 ..., главное изменить порядок значений.

Comment: После я работаю в цикле `$.each(obj, function(i, item){ html += `<div>....</div>`; });`

Comment: объект можно разбирать/пересобирать использую Object.entries / Object.fromEntries, но никакой гарантии по сохранению сортировки нету.